# VueJs: Working with v-class

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to assign a css class to a span element, whenver it push the EDIT button.

This is my **working** example in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/r3nepL7u/

BUT it only works, because I check if the title property of the edited object is equal to the title property of the todo object, instead I'd rather check if the two objects are equal.

Unfortunately this breaks my code, whenever I have the same property (e.g. titles) but different objects.

```
<td> 
    <span v-class="
        completed: todo.completed, 
        editing: editedTodo.title == todo.title">
        {{ todo.title }}
    </span>
</td>
```

Instead I would like to do something like this, where I check **todo == editedTodo**

```
<span v-class="
    completed: todo.completed, 
    editing: editedTodo == todo">
    {{ todo.title }}
</span>
```

Non Working Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/r3nepL7u/1/

How do I check if **todo** is equal with **editedTodo**. AND is there a better way, to use the v-class directive, instead of using inline expressions, meaning for more complicated calculations?

It seems to work fine in the todomvc example here:

Line 23: https://github.com/yyx990803/vue/blob/dev/examples/todomvc/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the reason it didn't work was pretty simple:

I falsely assinged just two properties and made an if statement to to see if the two objects are equal. I did this:

```
editTask: function (that) {
    this.editedTodo = {
        body: that.todo.body,
        completed: that.todo.completed
    };
},
```

Instead of asigning the actual object to the editedTodo, like this:

```
editTask: function (that) {
    this.editedTodo = that.todo;
},
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

### Conditional class names in `Vue.js`

Here is how you can do it based on the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

### 1st way

#### as boolean variable

You define a `boolean` variable in your `js` file and based on that it will set the class

`js` file

```
data: {
  isActive: true,
  hasError: false
}
```

`html` file

```
<div class="static"
     v-bind:class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }">
</div>
```

#### as object

you can also define an object with class names
`js` file

```
data: {
  classObject: {
    active: true,
    'text-danger': false
  }
}
```

`html` file

```
<div v-bind:class="classObject"></div>
```

### 2nd way

You define the "name of the class" variable in your `js` file and based on the `nameOfTheClass` it will set the class

`js` file

```
data: {
  nameOfTheClass: 'this-is-the-name-of-the-class'
}
```

`html` file

```
<div v-bind:class="nameOfTheClass"></div>
```

### 3rd way

You can set the name of the class in `js` and then evaluate with `if` statement in `html` file

`js` file
data: {
nameOfTheClass: 'this-is-the-name-of-class'
}

`html` file

```
<div v-bind:class="{ active: nameOfTheClass === 'this-is-the-name-of-class'}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to your View Model that does a deep comparison. For instance, create a method called `todoIsEqual` and then have it use LoDash to do the comparison:

```
[...]
methods: {
    todoIsEqual: function (todo_a, todo_b) {
        return _.isEqual(todo_a, todo_b);
    }
[...]
```

and use it like this:

```
<span v-class="
    completed: todo.completed, 
    editing: todoIsEqual(editedTodo, todo)">
    {{ todo.title }}
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your answer, but it didn't help. but I found the answer myself.